# Ich muss sagen,dass mein Hund die ganze Zeit eingesperrt war

Tags: grammaticality

1. Ich muss sagen,dass mein Hund die ganze Zeit eingesperrt wurde.
2. Ich muss sagen,dass mein Hund die ganze Zeit eingesperrt war.

Was ist richtig?

Comment: Beides. Das erste ist das "normale" Passiv mit *werden+Partizip II*, das zweite ist Zustandspassiv mit *sein+Partizip II*.

Answer (score 5):

Es gibt einen Bedeutungsunterschied. **"eingesperrt war"** ist im Infinitiv **"eingesperrt sein"**, während **"eingesperrt wurde"** andererseits **"eingesperrt werden"** entspricht.

**"Eingesperrt sein"** ist ein Zustand, während dessen der Hund ununterbrochen eingesperrt ist. **"Eingesperrt werden"** entspricht dem Vorgang, dass der Hund gerade eingesperrt wird.

Grammatisch sind beide richtig. Auch in verbaler Kommunikation werden nur wenige irritiert sein und in beiden Fällen annähernd das selbe verstehen.
Genau genommen ist es aber so, dass ein Hund, der die ganze Zeit eingesperrt **wird**, ständig dem Vorgang des Einsperrens ausgesetzt ist, also ununterbrochen jemand damit beschäftigt ist, den Hund einzusperren, was an sich nicht sinnvoll ist.

Es gibt jedoch noch eine mitschwingende Bedeutung bei der Verwendung von **"wurde"**. Während bei dem Ausdruck mit **"war"** verstanden wird, dass der Hund ununterbrochen eingesperrt war, wird der Ausdruck mit **"wurde"** dahingehend interpretiert, dass der Hund möglicherweise zwar manchmal heraus gelassen, aber dann sofort wieder eingesperrt wird und die meiste Zeit eingesperrt verbringen muss.